# Can't get python to write to next line repeatedly. Tried \r initially

Tags: python-2.7

I cannot get this program to work.

```
'''
Tasks are as follows:
1. The code to clean up the raw data and to use this information in the graphics package (R Project)
2. A graph of the month of birth and the number of the Omphaloceles and the number of children with Gastroschisis. (The counts in the file may be given as separate values. Use the sum of these two conditions in your graph.)
3. A graph of the Educational level of the mother versus the birth weight of the infant
4. A graph of the age of the mother and the trimester (not the month) of the start of prenatal care
'''


import re
nat=open('D:\Documents\Project\Nat2010us\VS2010NATL.DETAILUS.PUB', mode='rt')

#lists
Revision=[]
MonthofBirth=[]
MaternalAge=[]
MaternalEducation=[]
MonthofStartofPrenatalCare=[]
BirthWeight=[]
CongenitalAnomalies=[]
OmphaloceleGastroschisis=[]
#encoded lists
enrevision=[]
enmonthofbirth=[]
enmaternalage=[]
enmaternaleducation=[]
enmonthofstartofprenatalcare=[]
enbirthweight=[]
encongenitalanomalies=[]
enomphalocelegastroschisis=[]

#selecting data, S is Unrevised data and A Revised. For Month of Start of Prenatal Care I chose the two columns (246 and 258) that were both found in Unrevised and Revised sets.
for x in nat:
    Revision.append(x[6])
    MonthofBirth.append(x[18:20])
    MaternalAge.append(x[88:90])
    if x[6]=="S": MonthofStartofPrenatalCare.append(x[246])
    if x[6]=="A": MonthofStartofPrenatalCare.append(x[258])
    BirthWeight.append(x[470:472])
    CongenitalAnomalies.append(x[512])
    OmphaloceleGastroschisis.append(x[760])
    if x[6]=="S": MaternalEducation.append(x[155:157])
    if x[6]=="A": MaternalEducation.append(x[154])
nat.close()


#encoding the data, using 'en' as noting encoded lists
for x in Revision:
    if x=="S": enrevision.append("U")
    if x=="A": enrevision.append("R")
for x in MonthofBirth:
    if x=="01": enmonthofbirth.append("January")
    if x=="02": enmonthofbirth.append("February")
    if x=="03": enmonthofbirth.append("March")
    if x=="04": enmonthofbirth.append("April")
    if x=="05": enmonthofbirth.append("May")
    if x=="06": enmonthofbirth.append("June")
    if x=="07": enmonthofbirth.append("July")
    if x=="08": enmonthofbirth.append("August")
    if x=="09": enmonthofbirth.append("September")
    if x=="10": enmonthofbirth.append("October")
    if x=="11": enmonthofbirth.append("November")
    if x=="12": enmonthofbirth.append("December")
for x in MaternalAge:
    if x=="12": enmaternalage.append("10-12")
    if x=="13": enmaternalage.append("13")
    if x=="14": enmaternalage.append("14")
    if x=="15": enmaternalage.append("15")
    if x=="16": enmaternalage.append("16")
    if x=="17": enmaternalage.append("17")
    if x=="18": enmaternalage.append("18")
    if x=="19": enmaternalage.append("19")
    if x=="20": enmaternalage.append("20")
    if x=="21": enmaternalage.append("21")
    if x=="22": enmaternalage.append("22")
    if x=="23": enmaternalage.append("23")
    if x=="24": enmaternalage.append("24")
    if x=="25": enmaternalage.append("25")
    if x=="26": enmaternalage.append("26")
    if x=="27": enmaternalage.append("27")
    if x=="28": enmaternalage.append("28")
    if x=="29": enmaternalage.append("29")
    if x=="30": enmaternalage.append("30")
    if x=="31": enmaternalage.append("31")
    if x=="32": enmaternalage.append("32")
    if x=="33": enmaternalage.append("33")
    if x=="34": enmaternalage.append("34")
    if x=="35": enmaternalage.append("35")
    if x=="36": enmaternalage.append("36")
    if x=="37": enmaternalage.append("37")
    if x=="38": enmaternalage.append("38")
    if x=="39": enmaternalage.append("39")
    if x=="40": enmaternalage.append("40")
    if x=="41": enmaternalage.append("41")
    if x=="42": enmaternalage.append("42")
    if x=="43": enmaternalage.append("43")
    if x=="44": enmaternalage.append("44")
    if x=="45": enmaternalage.append("45")
    if x=="46": enmaternalage.append("46")
    if x=="47": enmaternalage.append("47")
    if x=="48": enmaternalage.append("48")
    if x=="49": enmaternalage.append("49")
    if x=="50": enmaternalage.append("50-54")
for x in MonthofStartofPrenatalCare:
    if x=="1": enmonthofstartofprenatalcare.append("1st Trimester")
    if x=="2": enmonthofstartofprenatalcare.append("2nd Trimester")
    if x=="3": enmonthofstartofprenatalcare.append("3rd Trimester")
    if x=="4": enmonthofstartofprenatalcare.append("No Prenatal Care")
    if x=="5": enmonthofstartofprenatalcare.append("unknown or not stated")
    if x==" ": enmonthofstartofprenatalcare.append("not on certificate")
for x in BirthWeight:
    if x=="01": enbirthweight.append("499 or less")
    if x=="02": enbirthweight.append("500-999")
    if x=="03": enbirthweight.append("1000-1499")
    if x=="04": enbirthweight.append("1500-1999")
    if x=="05": enbirthweight.append("2000-2499")
    if x=="06": enbirthweight.append("2500-2999")
    if x=="07": enbirthweight.append("3000-3499")
    if x=="08": enbirthweight.append("3500-3999")
    if x=="09": enbirthweight.append("4000-4499")
    if x=="10": enbirthweight.append("4500-4999")
    if x=="11": enbirthweight.append("5000-8165")
    if x=="12": enbirthweight.append("not stated")
for x in CongenitalAnomalies:
    if x=="1": encongenitalanomalies.append("anomaly reported")
    if x=="2": encongenitalanomalies.append("anomaly not reported")
    if x=="9": encongenitalanomalies.append("anomaly not classified")
    if x==" ": encongenitalanomalies.append("not on certificate")
for x in OmphaloceleGastroschisis:
    if x=="0": enomphalocelegastroschisis.append("not reporting")
    if x=="1": enomphalocelegastroschisis.append("reporting")

#encoding the two different education codes to be coded the same
for x in range(0, len (MaternalEducation)):
    if Revision[x]=="A":
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="1": enmaternaleducation.append("8th grade or less")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="2": enmaternaleducation.append("9th through 12th grade no diploma")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="3": enmaternaleducation.append("High school graduate or GED completed")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="4": enmaternaleducation.append("Some college credit but no degree")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="5" or MaternalEducation[x]=="6": enmaternaleducation.append("Associate and/or Bachelor")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="7" or MaternalEducation[x]=="8": enmaternaleducation.append("Master's or Doctorate")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="9": enmaternaleducation.append("not stated")
        if MaternalEducation[x]==" ": enmaternaleducation.append("blank")        
    if Revision[x]=="S":
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="00" or MaternalEducation[x]=="01-08": enmaternaleducation.append("8th grade or less")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="09" or MaternalEducation[x]=="10" or MaternalEducation[x]=="11": enmaternaleducation.append("9th through 12th grade no diploma")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="12": enmaternaleducation.append("High school graduate or GED completed")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="13": enmaternaleducation.append("Some college credit but no degree")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="14" or MaternalEducation[x]=="15" or MaternalEducation[x]=="16": enmaternaleducation.append("Associate and/or Bachelor")
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="17": enmaternaleducation.append("Master's or Doctorate") 
        if MaternalEducation[x]=="99": enmaternaleducation.append("not stated")
        if MaternalEducation[x]==" ": enmaternaleducation.append("blank")

#open new file for output of data
'''
enmonthofbirth=[]
enmaternalage=[]
enmaternaleducation=[]
enmonthofstartofprenatalcare=[]
enbirthweight=[]
encongenitalanomalies=[]
enomphalocelegastroschisis=[]
'''
#write header and then, for each line, replace values in the Natality file with the encoded values from encoded lists (line by line) in the outputforR file. Matching up values based on commonality they all share - length.
#\n to end line to  break to new line
f=open('D:\Documents\Project\outputforR.csv', mode='w')

f.write('month of birth'+','+'maternal age'+','+'maternal education'+','+'month of start of prenatal care'+','+'birth weight'+','+'congenital anomalies'+','+'omphalocele/gastroschisis')

for x in range(0,len(enmonthofbirth)):
    f.write(enmonthofbirth[x]+','+enmaternalage[x]+','+enmaternaleducation[x]+','+enmonthofstartofprenatalcare[x]+','+enbirthweight[x]+','+encongenitalanomalies[x]+','+enomphalocelegastroschisis[x]) \n

f.close()
```

I cannot seem to fix line 170. I've messed around with the \n in different ways to try to get this file to write so I can move on to putting my data in R. My headers will write and open up in Excel just fine, but I cannot get Python to write the values in each list underneath its appropriate header. I'm told I need \n to make it go to next row, but it will only allow \ by itself, which doesn't work. Removing \n also doesn't work. \ and nothing leave me with exactly what is in this link. below.

Below is a link to an image of my excel file once written.

http://i.imgur.com/GDReiQh.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `\n` from following line:

```
f.write(enmonthofbirth[x]+','+...) \n
#                                 ^^^
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to write, write it as follow:

```
f.write(enmonthofbirth[x]+','+... + '\n')
```

Comment: @ falsetru removing `\n` gets rid of the error, but the file does not write correctly. It writes all of those values in the same row. I need Python to move on to the next row every time it writes `...','+enomphalocelegastroschisis[x])`

Comment: of course, I sit here for an hour trying various ways to move `\n` around, and the one thing I miss is adding `+` after my last list. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.